# Mac OS X: Icons for X11 windows

Tags: macos, xorg, xquartz

X11 windowing system allows setting per-window icons to be used when the window is minimized. It is odd that Xquartz / X11.app on OS X doesn't use this icon, substituting it for its default "X" icon.

Is there a way to get Xquartz's window management layer to actually set the proper per-window icon for the X11 windows displayed by Xquartz?